# Trying to display large amounts of text based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, html

To preface, I'm a complete novice at anything besides basic HTML, so I appreciate any help I can get (with "for dummies" level explanation if possible), and I apologize if I'm missing some sort of fundamental rule or understanding in my question.

I would like each selection in a dropdown menu (about 40 options) to display a set of text (each different based on the selection).  Each set of text is multiple paragraphs and would ideally also contain formatting (bullet lists, etc.). I'm hoping to avoid having to reload the page every time a new selection is chosen, if humanly possible.  The other challenge is that I don't think there is any practical way to include ALL of the text in the code directly, meaning I need to find a way to load from an outside source.

I had tried playing with this code (found elsewhere on the site):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var textBlocks = new Array( 
        'Text block one', 
        'Text block two', 
        'Text block three');

    function changeText(elemid) { 
        var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex; 
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind]; 
    } 
</script>

<form> 
    <select id="whatever" onChange="changeText('whatever');"> 
        <option value="0">Select</option> 
        <option value="1">One</option> 
        <option value="2">Two</option> 
    </select><br> 
</form>
```

To try and be able to include a text file or anything else in the array. (I know there is a way to load text files via PHP, but couldn't figure out if I could somehow include that in the array.)

I'd appreciate any help with the above code or an entirely new suggestion.

Comment: Do you also have an element called `display` somewhere in your HTML?  That's the element this line of code is trying to update: `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind];`

Comment: Because you're only dealing with text, it might not be unreasonable to load everything into the HTML, hide it with CSS, and then just turn it on based on their selection. Or you can just put them into an external file and load in only the section you need. And to circumvent the refresh, it's gonna need to be done with ajax. This could all be handled on the client without even needing PHP.

Comment: @slime it doesn't HAVE to use ajax. Ajax is a bit over the top for static content that needs to be hidden.

Comment: @press, if its a lot of content, it will clutter the page. Loading from an external source can be very useful.

Comment: I should have been more clear; ajax needed if going the external route.

Comment: @zgr024 I do agree with that.

Comment: @ochi Yes, I do. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @slime I am hopefully trying to avoid loading everything into the 1 file because I have 50 (was 10 off in my original guess) different blocks of text to display, and each is about 1000 words. It's sounding like ajax is maybe my best bet, I just unfortunately know absolutely nothing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a lot easier with jQuery but with pure Javascript this will do the trick!

```js
function displayStuff() {
    var e = document.getElementById('selecter');
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    switch (val) {
        case "1":
            document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case "2":
            document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
            break;
    }
    
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="selecter" onchange="displayStuff()">
    <option selected>Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div class="hidden" id="one">Hidden ONE text.</div>
<div class="hidden" id="two">Hidden TWO text.</div>
```

### EDIT

Here's a simple AJAX call loading a file based on the selected value in the dropdown. It then replaces a single `div`s `innerHTML` with the `responseText`.

```js
function displayStuff() {

  var e = document.getElementById('selecter');
  var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var xmlhttp;

  if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

   switch (val) {
     case "1":
       xmlhttp.open("GET", "page1.html", false);
       xmlhttp.send();
       break;
   }

  document.getElementById("hider").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;


}
```

Comment: I like the use of a switch here.

Comment: I dont like the use of inline js in the HTML

Comment: @Press Thanks. I'm not sure I'll go with this off the bat, as I'm trying to avoid having to load 50 text selections at 1000 words each into the one file, but I will come back to this if I can't figure out another solution.  The only issue with this is, it seems to just add the next hidden div below the first one instead of replacing the text.

Comment: I can modify it a bit so it will hide the current text and show the new selected. However, you're best not to hard-code THAT much into your single page. Like what was mentioned above can use ajax to load in the HTML from a separate page(s).

Comment: @Press Exactly; I'd rather not be putting that much onto the page.  I know exactly 0 things about AJAX, though, so I'd need something fairly specific to get me going.

Comment: @outtheairlock I updated my answer. This should work for you. It isn't, by any means, perfect. However, it should work for you.

Comment: @Press - I can't thank you enough: this is working wonderfully and accomplishing exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should be loading data from the server based on some sort of Id using ajax.
However if you want to hard code it, you can do something like (quite simple):

```js
var data = {
    0: "Large Amount of text",
    1: "Some more text",
    2: "You get the drill ..."
};

function changeText(id) {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data[id];
}
```

```html
<select id="whatever" onchange="changeText(this.value);">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
```

In other scenario you do your ajax call (pseudo-code since I'm not hardcore enough to do ajax without jquery):

```
function changeText(id) {
   showAFancyAjaxLoader();

   fetchContentFromServer(id).done(function(response) { 
      hideFancyAjaxLoader();
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response;
   });
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm trying to avoid loading everything in full into the document, as I have 50 different bits of text, each at around 1000 words. That'd be a mess. (I'm also not sure, but don't think, I could format using your option?)  As for the ajax, I don't know anything about it at all - is there a good resource to reference for this kind of issue?